# firebase/ Android: Get image at the same time as data

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

In firebase Realtime Database I save information about a product, in firebase Storage I save the respective image of the product. I want that when calling the data of a product also obtain the image, I know how to call the data and place it in editText but I don't know how to call and display the image in an ImageView.

This is how I save the image:

```
private void SaveImage(){
    Verificar();
    if (ver == true){
        errorTitulo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        sId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        StorageReference filePath = 
        fireStorage.child("ProductosImg").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());

        filePath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new 
        OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Crear();
            }
        });
    }else {
        errorTitulo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

This is how I save the product data:

```
    private void Crear(){
    Producto p = new Producto();
    p.setUid(sId);
    p.setCategoria(sCategoria);
    p.setNombre(sNombre);
    p.setDescripcion(sDescrip);
    p.setValor(sValor);
    fireData.child("Producto").child(p.getUid()).setValue(p);
    pDialog.dismiss();
    Toast.makeText(PaginaActivity.PaginaA, "Producto creado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I think that when saving the image with the same identification as the data that I could call it, but I don't know how to put the same id.

Answer (score 0):

You can create random id names with the [push()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#push()) method. If there is going to be more than 1 product for every user, create the path with the push() method after the uid part. And also use that hash when creating the image's path so that you can know which image belongs to which product.

To display the image you can both use Glide and Picasso:

```
StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("ProductosImg/randomHashOfProduct.jpg");

Glide.with(this /* context */)
    .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
    .load(storageReference)
    .into(imageView);
```